# Pandas command to skip first empty column

Tags: python, pandas

While reading excel from pandas, I need to skip first column which is completely empty. I tried skip columns but that didn't work. e.g :

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel("c:/test.xlsx", sheet_name='ABC',skiprows=2, skipcolumns=1)
```

Appreciate help!

Comment: You can do `df=df.iloc[:,1:]`

Comment: Do you know how many columns you have beforehand?

Comment: @BilltheLizard- There will be more than 200 columns

Comment: @Ram  thanks , it worked

Comment: How about `usecols`?